# How can I reset MIUI 11 features?

Tags: xiaomi, miui, redmi

I turned off MIUI optimization and some features were lost and I can't retrieve them after I turn it on again.

[image]

Comment: I've done that but I still can't get back the MIUI 11 UI display

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable Developer options on your MI device.
To unblock the developer options,

1. Go to Settings >About, find the MIUI version and tap 7 times continuously.
2. You could see a message “You have enabled developer option” once you have successfully done that.
3. To access developer options, Goto Settings > Additional settings > Developer options.
4. Now scroll down till the end to see the option to toggle MIUI Optimization. You’ll need to restart the device once you enable the option.

   - Even though it is just a toggle which we enable, it causes the way which the system behaves, in turn changes the way many apps behave.

[Source](https://technicles.com/miui-optimization-developer-tools-side-effects/)